# Use uploaded file directly from its tmp location

Tags: php, email, file-upload

I have a small form in which the user uploads a file. What I want to do is to e-mail the file directly from its tmp location, without moving it first; because there's no need to store it on the server. Because PHP removes the file from the tmp folder after execution of the script, this would be ideal.

I'm using Manuel Lemos's fantastic [Mime message e-mail class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html), and can do this:

```
$tmp_file = '/www/vhosts/mysite.be/subdomains/subdomainname/httpdocs'.$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$attachment=array(
    "FileName" => $_FILES['attachment']['name'],
    "Content-Type" => $_FILES['attachment']['type'],
    "Data" => $tmp_file,
    "Disposition" => "attachment"
);
$email_message->AddFilePart($attachment);
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to retrieve the file from its tmp location. I'm on a shared hosting system.

Can anyone share viewpoints / answers? Looking forward to your views.

P.S.: Please note there is no problem with upload limits / timeouts / enctype ...

Comment: Have you tried verifying that there is some issue relating to the uploaded file? For example by logging `is_readable()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The file is supposed to be readable (according to is_readable()). Problem is that the script tells me: "could not open part file"

Comment: I've modified the script like so `FileName" => $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']` and now it works, problem is that it now sends the file with name `glkjmlksjf` and without extention. Any way to address this?

Comment: That's most likely a shortcoming of the library you are using. I'm not about to dig into that. I'd advise however that you should use a better known library, e.g. zetaMail from the [zetaComponents](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights and tips. I will be looking into zetaComponents. Of course I understand that going into the mailclass I'm using is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to put the directory for the `$tmp_file` as the tmp_name already contains this. Also check that the file exists as a way of debugging it.

```
$tmp_file = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];

if (file_exists($tmp_file)) {
     echo "yay";
}
else {
     echo "nay :-(";
}
```

See what happens after this.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. To define $tmp_file is not necessary. I've gathered now that the file exists. Another problem now appears, as described in the third comment on the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Again, debug it by echo'ing the `$_FILES['attachment']['name']` if that is the correct name of the file you'll need to go back to the class you got it from and see how it works as it doesn't appear to be using `FileName` (maybe the attachment array is not constructed right).

Comment: Thank you! Deeper research shows me that the file is sent by mail with its temp name, but with an extention. I can live with this. It's functional in its current form thanks to you and Till Helge Helwig. Have a good day.